# Can different kinds of dogs mate?

Tags: reproduction

This was inspired by a show in which two different kinds of dogs, who were neighbors, "dated," in order to bring their human neighbors together. This is a theme seen in Disney's "101 Dalmations" or "The Lady and the Tramp."

Can dogs of similar sizes, say Rotweilers or pitbulls actually interbreed? Can any of them mate with say, wolves? And under what circumances?

(I am "encouraged" by the fact that horses and donkeys can produce mules, and lions and tigers can produce "liger" or "tigons." Also of note is that dogs are of the same [species](https://www.itis.gov/servlet/SingleRpt/SingleRpt?search_topic=TSN&search_value=726821#null) as wolves, and "domestic dogs" are actually a subspecies.)

Comment: You don't need to restrict this to similar sizes. As long as the female is not much smaller than the male (making the uterus too small for successful pregnancy), it is possible (although it might require help for the mating act or even artificial insemination).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the vast majority of dogs out there are not pure bred. They are therefore a cross between two breeds. Consider [cockapoos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cockapoo) for example. The offsprings of a Cocker Spaniel and a poodle is called a cockapoo.

Comment: Yes, and domestic dogs can interbreed with both wolves and coyotes.  Also wolves and coyotes interbreed, producing the "coywolf", which is apparently becoming a significant predator in eastern North America: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coywolf